# how to use JQuery $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have seen and tried a half dozen variations of $.when and $.Deferred but I cannot get this to work correctly.  The code below SHOULD DO the following:

1.) User clicks login which calls the login function.

2.) login calls renderNavbar which needs to execute a callback from the server.

3.) After renderNavbar has retrieved data and AFTER renderNavbar has set the html property of #navbar then login should call toggleLoginState.

What actually happens is login calls renderNavbar then immediately calls toggleLoginState without waiting for the callback inside renderNavbar.  How do I fix this??  (BTW renderNavbar and toggleLoginState are called independently of each other in other places in code.  One cannot call the other directly.).

```
var app = {

this.login = function () {
    $.when(app.renderNavbar()).done(app.toggleLoginState(1));  // wrong does not work


}


this.renderNavbar = function ()
{
    return $.when($.get('/Home/Navbar')).done(function (data) {
        $('#navbar').html(data);  // this line must complete before the call the to toggleLoginState is made
    });
}

this.toggleLoginState = function (state)
{
    if (state == 1) {// yada}  // this line should execute after #navbar is set
}

}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, a dangling `)}` in `login`.

Comment: dangle removed... was the result of snipping out code.  The answer you provided is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `$.when` anywhere in your code. `$.get` returns a promise that you can invoke `done` on directly. You're just wrapping that promise again. That same promise gets returned from `renderNavbar`, and you wrap it a *third* time with `$.when`.

The actual underlying problem is that you're not passing callback functions to `done`, you're just invoking code instantly and passing the return values to `done`.

Your code should look like this, with *functions* being passed to `done`:

```
this.renderNavbar = function () {
    return $.get('/Home/Navbar').done(function (data) {
        $('#navbar').html(data);  // this line must complete before the call the to toggleLoginState is made
    });
}


this.login = function () {
    app.renderNavbar().done(function () {
      app.toggleLoginState(1));
    });
}
```

The difference is that you're doing this....

```
// invoke doSomething() immediately, pass return value to done
$(...).done(doSomething())
```

when you need to do this:

```
// give done a function to invoke in the future
$(...).done(function () { doSomething() });
```

Comment: Wow you are fast and spot on.  Interesting that the call to toggleLoginState has to be wrapped in a function even though it is a function..... how weird.  Thank you meagar.

Comment: @Sam  It has to be wrapped because you're *invoking* it. If you pass `functionName` to `done`, that's fine. You cannot pass `functionName(1)` to `done`. That's an invocation, and it's the return value that gets passed.

Comment: Or just `.done(doSomething)` where `doSomething` is a function

Comment: OMG such a rookie mistake.  Thanks for explaining that.